# Why is there no error when calling an undefined function in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/vr0dkwrh/1/

Basically, I'm calling a function that doesn't exist in the scope. Why is there no error shown in the browser? (I have tested with Firefox 38.1 and IE 11).

When anchor 'click me' is clicked, `go()` will be called.

When anchor 'click me2' is clicked, `go2()` will be called but it doesn't exists and there is no error in the console.

For the record, I'm new to AngularJS and I was requested to learn it in such short notice (2 days...).

Could someone tell me if this is normal behaivor in AngularJS?

I had to choose 1.2.1 version in JSFiddle but I'm using 1.4.4 locally.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>AngularJS Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-lg-12" ng-app="app" ng-strict-di>
      <div ng-controller="EditableRowCtrl">
          <a ng-href="#here" ng-click="go()" >click me</a><br />
          <a ng-href="#here2" ng-click="go2()" >click me2</a><br />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../libs/angularjs.js"></script>
    <script src="../app/app-test1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

function GoodController1($scope, $http, $filter) {
  $scope.go = function(){
    console.log('asd');
    //notexists();
  };
}
GoodController1.$inject = ["$scope", "$http", "$filter"];

angular.module("app", [])
.controller('EditableRowCtrl', GoodController1);
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the manual puts it, Angular's template expression evaluation is explicitly ***forgiving***:

> Expression evaluation is forgiving to `undefined` and `null`. In
>   JavaScript, evaluating `a.b.c` throws an exception if `a` is not an
>   object. While this makes sense for a general purpose language, the
>   expression evaluations are primarily used for data binding, which
>   often look like this:
>
> ```
> {{a.b.c}}
> ```
>
> It makes more sense to show nothing than to throw an
>   exception if `a` is `undefined` (perhaps we are waiting for the server
>   response, and it will become defined soon). If expression evaluation
>   wasn't forgiving we'd have to write bindings that clutter the code,
>   for example:
>
> ```
> {{((a||{}).b||{}).c}}
> ```
>
> **Similarly, invoking a function `a.b.c()` on `undefined` or `null` simply
>   returns `undefined`.**

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Angular uses a custom expression evaluation engine which is not Javascript. Its syntax allows a narrow subset of Javascript, but the execution is entirely custom.

Comment: Is there a way to make it strict? Or is it recommended to leave it as is?

Comment: As written, it's explicitly forgiving because it makes sense in templates. Leaving it as is is recommended. Throwing an error at runtime doesn't help anyone. Use E2E testing if you want to ensure your code behaves as required and that all functions are defined and working.